# I using caliburn.micro with multiproject solution, need to identify assemblies to bootstrapper in main project so it find other projects

Tags: c#, wpf, caliburn.micro

I have added dependencies references using the reference add.
in the bootstrapper I have added using ProjectTwo; and using ProjectThree.
the class is defin3ed as public class Bootstrapper : BoostrapperBase  there is a using for Caliburn.Micro
I am overriding Configure()
as follows

```
 protected override void Configure()
        {
            _container.Instance(_container);

            _container
                .Singleton<IWindowManager, WindowManager>()
                .Singleton<IEventAggregator, EventAggregator>();

            GetType().Assembly.GetTypes()
                .Where(type => type.IsClass)
                .Where(type => type.Name.EndsWith("ViewModel"))
                .ToList()
                .ForEach(viewModelType => _container.RegisterPerRequest(
                    viewModelType, viewModelType.ToString(), viewModelType));

            _container
                .PerRequest<Demo3ViewModel>();
        }
```

I added the last two lines to see if VS2019 could 'see' the ViewModel I want to reference in ProjectThree.
It cannot.

I have been using Caliburn.Micro with C#, WPF for several months and having success with a single project approach.

But my main application I am developing is getting larger and more complex and I would like to break it into different projects that can see each other.

I don't know how to build an assembly reference. probably obvious but there are parts of C# that still allude me
Any suggestions?
Thank you in advance

Comment: its difficult to understand what you want exactly, could you describe precisily with a concrete sample?

Comment: I will try to model the structure Solution(Two Project Solution) contains 2 projects, Project Main and ProjectTwo. I want to call(or use) a View-ViewModel pair from ProjectTwo in ProjectOne. From what I have read the secret is in the bootstrapper which identifies assemblies. I can get the assembly for ProjectMain as I am running fromthere (startup project) but I dont know how to make or describe an assembly for the other project. I hope that makes more sense. I can not seem to refernce ProjectTwo from ProjectMain using Caliburn.Micro methodology. Thank you.

Comment: Do you have a sample project that recreates this issue?